Should I still use precompiled header file in my C++ 20 module based code if I use non-module headers like windows.h?
I have read a couple of articles about the new C++ 20 feature "modules" and trying to use them in my new project. But what I don't clearly understand is should I disable the Precompiled Header in my compiler options or not?
From my understanding, all the included headers in my sources (module implementation files) go to global module scope and compiled only once, so there is no use of precompiled header anymore.
In my case I'm writing a Windows DLL and which highly depends on the windows.h header file. It's pretty large header file and it's not a C++ 20 module interface file, just ordinary header file.
My module implementation files look something like this:
// ModuleA.cpp
module;

#include <windows.h>

module ModuleA;

void Initialize() {
   // Some code..
}

There are many of such *.cpp files in my project.
Besides, I also include the windows.h header in my *.ixx (module interface) files too, because without this header, they know nothing about DWORD, SHORT, UINT, APIENTRY types. Ofcourse, I could use unsigned long instead of DWORD and __stdcall instead of APIENTRY etc., but this is not very convenient for me.
I'm afraid that if I disable the Precompiled Header option in my Visual Studio 2022 C++ compiler options, windows.h file will be compiled more than once.

Which compiler are you talking about? MSVC? Please tag the compiler, because precompiled headers are a compiler-specific functionality.

@3CxEZiVlQ None of the suggested duplicates clearly answers the question, especially not if it is about MSVC.

The working of precompiled headers is implementation (e.g. compiler and preprocessor) specific, not something the standard specifies. Some compiler vendors will use a scheme that is aware of or provides benefit with C++20 modules, others will not - it depends on development priorities when implementing the compiler. You need to test (e.g. build a non-trivial project using your compiler without and with precompiled headers, do measurements [compile time, incremental build times, etc], and compare). You may need to repeat the tests whenever you update the compiler (or adopt a different compiler)

You should not use them. Precompiled headers solve the long compilation time issue. Modules solve this issue too. One of the duplicated question answered this but you did not want to draw your own conclusions based on other questions. Moreover precompiled headers have fundamental issues, they are sensitive to MSVC versions and settings, such issues are seldom/solved in modules.

@3CxEZiVlQ The duplicate answers don't have clear answers, well at least for me. They just show module-only code without mixing legacy header files with module based approach. I understand that if you use only modules then you definitely no need for precompiled header. But in my case I mix modules with legacy headers, and the answer is not clear to me.

Do you need MACRO defined from <windows.h> ? else import <windows.h> might do the trick, and depending of MACRO needed, a wrapper module might be sufficient.

Considering that macros like SHORT and UINT have been the same for 40 years, I would think it is very convenient to use short and unsigned instead. Especially if you oitherwise have to include half a million lines of headers.

Does the implementation of your dll depend on windows.h? Or does your dll's API depend on windows.h. Avoiding the latter could avoid a lot of issues too.

My question is not about how to replace windows.h or anything like that. It could be any other *.h library. The question is does the module global scope do the same stuff as the precompiled headers do (MSVC). In modules-based design we have Module-Interface files *.ixx and Module-Implementation files, similar to regular header and source files. But when you deal with regular headers usually I don't include other headers in it, but in the source files. But when it comes to modules, your *.ixx files require to include all the headers, and your implementation files include the same headers. :(

Since I didn't get any answers here, I decided to test C++ 20 modules vs classic code compilation speed.
I created 4 of C++ 20 projects:

Classic code (no C++ 20 modules) without Precompiled Header file.
Classic code (no C++ 20 modules) with Precompiled Header file.
Modern C++ 20 modules based code without Precompiled Header file.
Modern C++ 20 modules based code with Precompiled Header file.

Each of these projects contain 500 header files and 500 source files for Classic code projects.
And 500 module-interface files (.ixx) with 500 module-implementation files (.cpp) for Modern C++ 20 module based projects.
All the source and module-implementation files have #include "framework.h" for non Precompiled Header version, and #include "pch.h" for the version with Precompiled Header file enabled.
The "framework.h" file includes following headers:
// framework.h
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <iostream>

Here are the results:
// █ Classic code, no Precompiled Header █
1>All 510 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.
1>Finished generating code
1>NoModules-NoPCH.vcxproj -> \x64\Release\NoModules-NoPCH.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 22:05:55 and took 03:50.216 minutes ==========
Build output folder size: 659 MB (691 732 507 bytes)


// █ Classic code with Precompiled Header █
1>All 510 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.
1>Finished generating code
1>NoModules-PCH.vcxproj -> \x64\Release\NoModules-PCH.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 22:06:39 and took 04.573 seconds ==========
Build output folder size: 90.9 MB (95 344 891 bytes)


// █ Modern C++ 20 code (Modules), no Precompiled Header █
1>All 515 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.
1>Finished generating code
1>Modules-Cpp20.vcxproj -> \x64\Release\Modules-Cpp20.exe
1>Done building project "Modules-Cpp20.vcxproj".
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 22:12:03 and took 04:30.789 minutes ==========
Build output folder size: 1.47 GB (1 586 401 470 bytes)


// █ Modern C++ 20 code (Modules) with Precompiled Header █
1>All 510 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.
1>Finished generating code
1>Modules-Cpp20-PCH.vcxproj -> \x64\Release\Modules-Cpp20-PCH.exe
1>Done building project "Modules-Cpp20-PCH.vcxproj".
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 22:13:10 and took 19.306 seconds ==========
Build output folder size: 249 MB (261 284 309 bytes)

So far the fastest compilation was the Classic C++ code with Precompiled Headers enabled, took 04.573 seconds. Created *.obj-like files: 90.9 MB (95 344 891 bytes).
and the slowest was Modern C++ 20 code with modules, but without Precompiled Header file, it took 04:30.789 minutes. Also created a lot of *.obj like stuff of 1.47 GB (1 586 401 470 bytes).
I uploaded my test projects to GitHub: cpp20-compiler-tests.
I don't know maybe these tests are not best, and real world projects may show different performance. I don't know.
But I believe that it answers to my question:

Should I use Precompiled Header with C++ 20 Modules or not?

and It shows that the answer is YES.
It shows that the C++ 20 Global Module Fragment can't replace Precompiled Header file, well at least not today. Maybe one day, who knows...
